# ARCore Unity - Touch / Update frame problem

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

I'am currently creating a AR apps using ARCore and Unity3D in C#.

My goal is to place, via touching the screen, two objects on the surface. After getting the distance between the two objects, I place programmatically several objects between the two main objects.

The code is placed in the Update() function because it require Touch and some of the buttons needs to blink.

I technically successfully arrived to realize it, but the problem is that the Touch in the update() function is called at every frames, and perturb the block lines who should updates, even with conditional blocks around it it perturb.

The code block DrawPoints() create and display the objects between the two objects "target1" and "target2", it update well and stay in place. But if I touch the screen it disappear.

```
if (mIsSecondTargetVisible)
    {
      DrawPoints(target1, target2, Color.red, 0.2f);
    }
```

I tried changing the place of this block within the Update() function, but still same result.

```
void Update()
{

    _UpdateApplicationLifecycle();

    // Hide snackbar when currently tracking at least one plane.
    Session.GetTrackables<DetectedPlane>(m_AllPlanes);
    bool showSearchingUI = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < m_AllPlanes.Count; i++)
    {
        if (m_AllPlanes[i].TrackingState == TrackingState.Tracking)
        {
            showSearchingUI = false;
            break;
        }
}

SearchingForPlaneUI.SetActive(showSearchingUI);

Touch touch;
if (Input.touchCount < 1 || (touch = Input.GetTouch(0)).phase !=     TouchPhase.Began)
    {
        return;
    }

    TrackableHit hit;
    TrackableHitFlags raycastFilter =     TrackableHitFlags.PlaneWithinPolygon |
        TrackableHitFlags.FeaturePointWithSurfaceNormal;

                          if(!EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(touch.fingerId))
    {
        if (Frame.Raycast(touch.position.x, touch.position.y, raycastFilter, out hit))
        {

if ((hit.Trackable is DetectedPlane) &&
                        Vector3.Dot(FirstPersonCamera.transform.position - hit.Pose.position,
  hit.Pose.rotation * Vector3.up) < 0)
 {
 Debug.Log("Hit at back of the current DetectedPlane");
 }
 else
 {

anchor = hit.Trackable.CreateAnchor(hit.Pose);

if (mIsFirsttargetVisible == false){                     
target1 = Instantiate(cubes, hit.Pose.position, hit.Pose.rotation);
target1.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.02f, 0.001f, 0.02f);
target1.transform.parent = anchor.transform;
mIsFirsttargetVisible = true;                    
}

else if (mIsSecondTargetVisible == false){
target2 = Instantiate(cubes, hit.Pose.position, hit.Pose.rotation);
target2.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.02f, 0.001f, 0.02f);
target2.transform.parent = anchor.transform;
mIsSecondTargetVisible = true;
              }
            }
        }
    }

if (mIsSecondTargetVisible)
    {
      DrawPoints(target1, target2, Color.red, 0.2f);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
The actual result is :
1. Placing the two main objects, by touch screen, work.
2. After this, the function DrawPoints() display objets and update well, but disappears when touching the screen. 

The expected result is that : 
1. Touch is only used for placing the first two Objects "target", and for some UI buttons.
2.the function DrawPoints should updated well but not be perturbed by touch on screen.
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, here is the final code, plus explanation. Note that the order of the line blocks is important.

```
void Update()
{

_UpdateApplicationLifecycle();

// Hide snackbar when currently tracking at least one plane.
Session.GetTrackables<DetectedPlane>(m_AllPlanes);
bool showSearchingUI = true;
for (int i = 0; i < m_AllPlanes.Count; i++)
{
    if (m_AllPlanes[i].TrackingState == TrackingState.Tracking)
    {
        showSearchingUI = false;
        break;
    }
}

SearchingForPlaneUI.SetActive(showSearchingUI);


Touch touch;
if (Input.touchCount < 1 || (touch = Input.GetTouch(0)).phase !=     TouchPhase.Began)
{
    return;
}

// Should not handle input if the player is pointing on UI.
if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(touch.fingerId))
{
    return;
}


if (mIsSecondTargetVisible)
{
    return;
}

TrackableHit hit;
TrackableHitFlags raycastFilter =         TrackableHitFlags.PlaneWithinPolygon |
TrackableHitFlags.FeaturePointWithSurfaceNormal;

if (Frame.Raycast(touch.position.x, touch.position.y, raycastFilter, out hit))
    {

if ((hit.Trackable is DetectedPlane) && Vector3.Dot(FirstPersonCamera.transform.position - hit.Pose.position,
  hit.Pose.rotation * Vector3.up) < 0)
 {
 Debug.Log("Hit at back of the current DetectedPlane");
 }
 else
 {

anchor = hit.Trackable.CreateAnchor(hit.Pose);

if (mIsFirsttargetVisible == false){                     
target1 = Instantiate(cubes, hit.Pose.position, hit.Pose.rotation);
target1.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.02f, 0.001f, 0.02f);
target1.transform.parent = anchor.transform;
mIsFirsttargetVisible = true;                    
}

else if (mIsSecondTargetVisible == false){
target2 = Instantiate(cubes, hit.Pose.position, hit.Pose.rotation);
target2.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.02f, 0.001f, 0.02f);
target2.transform.parent = anchor.transform;
mIsSecondTargetVisible = true;
          }
    }
}

if (mIsSecondTargetVisible)
{
  DrawPoints(target1, target2, Color.red, 0.2f);
}
}
```

Below, To permit to click on UI button without passing through, I added:

```
if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(touch.fingerId))
{
return;
}
```

Regarding the line block below, who need to display objects continuously but is perturb by the touch screen Arcore raycast :

```
if (mIsSecondTargetVisible)
{
  DrawPoints(target1, target2, Color.red, 0.2f);
}
```

I added this condition above the Touch Frame Raycast,in the aim to     escape the touch:

```
if (mIsSecondTargetVisible)
{
return;
}
```